# How do I save my undo history as well to my blender file?

Tags: workflow

I want to get my entire session's undo history back when I load a Blender file. 
This would allow me to undo as far as would have been possible, had I not closed Blender.

Can any in-built feature or plugin support this?

Comment: I wanted to ask the same for Blender 2.8* and I found this.

Comment: Related info: Blender's unusual handling of undo steps [Devtalk: Undo Performance Must Be Addressed](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/undo-performance-must-be-addressed/8838/11). Blender basically reloads *the entire scene* when you Undo a step. The backup scenes are kept in RAM, never actually written to disk.

Comment: And an interesting thread on ux.stackexchange: [Undo History - Why limit it?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/12629).

Answer (score 9):

as you mentioned there is a limitation.
this test shows you how many steps you can undo. In my pc I can undo only 32 steps:

```
import bpy

for i in range(0,100):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(i, 0, 0))
    bpy.ops.ed.undo_push(message="Add Cube")


for i in range(0,100):
    bpy.ops.ed.undo()
```

I decompiled undo script

```
void ED_undo_push(bContext *C, const char *str)
{
  CLOG_INFO(&LOG, 1, "name='%s'", str);
  WM_file_tag_modified();

  wmWindowManager *wm = CTX_wm_manager(C);
  int steps = U.undosteps;

  /* Ensure steps that have been initialized are always pushed,
   * even when undo steps are zero.
   *
   * Note that some modes (paint, sculpt) initialize an undo step before an action runs,
   * then accumulate changes there, or restore data from it in the case of 2D painting.
   *
   * For this reason we need to handle the undo step even when undo steps is set to zero.
   */
  if ((steps <= 0) && wm->undo_stack->step_init != NULL) {
    steps = 1;
  }
  if (steps <= 0) {
    return;
  }

  /* Only apply limit if this is the last undo step. */
  if (wm->undo_stack->step_active && (wm->undo_stack->step_active->next == NULL)) {
    BKE_undosys_stack_limit_steps_and_memory(wm->undo_stack, steps - 1, 0);
  }

  BKE_undosys_step_push(wm->undo_stack, C, str);

  if (U.undomemory != 0) {
    const size_t memory_limit = (size_t)U.undomemory * 1024 * 1024;
    BKE_undosys_stack_limit_steps_and_memory(wm->undo_stack, -1, memory_limit);
  }

  if (CLOG_CHECK(&LOG, 1)) {
    BKE_undosys_print(wm->undo_stack);
  }
}
```

you can see how limitation calculated:

```
const size_t memory_limit = (size_t)U.undomemory * 1024 * 1024;
```

as  @Jachym Michal said in comments increasing this limitation is not recommended

I suggest you use [Git](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/what-is-git).you can easily undo (checkout) by git commands

> Git is a distributed version control system for tracking changes in source code during software development.

but if you like the automatic way you can commit after each change:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

import re

# undo step
step = 0
# repository path
repoDir = 'C:/Users/Kamali/Desktop/Test'

def gitCommit(message):
    global step
    step += 1
    cmd = 'git add . && git commit -am '+message
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, cwd=repoDir)
    p.wait()

def undo():
  global step
  step -= 1
  checkoutTo(step)


# check out to specific step
def checkoutTo(Index):
    cmd = 'git checkout ' + getStepRevision()
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, cwd=repoDir)
    p.wait()


# get specific revision from git log history 546bece2c66acb454878500689e3017b92c43d28
def getStepRevision():
    cmd = 'powershell.exe git show HEAD~'+str(step)+' --pretty=oneline --no-patch'
    p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True, cwd=repoDir)
    output = p.stdout.read()
    p.wait()
    
    revision = re.search('(.*?)\s',output.decode('utf-8')).group(1)
    print(revision)
```

---

## Update

if you don't know git commands
you can use [git extension](http://gitextensions.github.io/)

after you undo (check out) you have to close and reopen blender to refresh
but these lines of code help you to reload it easy

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=bpy.data.filepath)
```

### [Tutorial](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PdtVcPD2ZWjJyvJegTs_WGSl70XXk_OQ/view?usp=sharing)

run this code and see what happened!!!

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

import bpy

repoDir = 'C:/Users/Kamali/Desktop/New folder'

for i in range(0,100):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(i, 0, 0))
    bpy.ops.ed.undo_push(message="Add Cube")


def gitCommit(message):
    bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath=bpy.data.filepath)
    add = 'git add .'
    p = subprocess.Popen(add, cwd=repoDir)
    p.wait()
    commit = 'git commit -m ' + message
    p = subprocess.Popen(commit, cwd=repoDir)
    p.wait()
```

I could commit 100 steps with code

[image]